# What topologic relation means "interior-disjoint"?

Tags: jts-topology-suite, de-9im

I am using the **[JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html)**, and trying to write an expression that means "shape A and shape B are interior disjoint".

I read this **[documentation page](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/index.html)** but I don't entirely understand the relations.

The "disjoint" relation (which is the opposite of "intersects") means that the two shapes don't have *any* point in common, including the boundary.

The "overlaps" relation means that the two shapes have some points in common but no shape is covered by the other. Thus the "not overlaps" relation doesn't take care of the case in which one shape entirely covers the other.

There is a function that defines the "DE-9IM Intersection Matrix", but, I couldn't figure out what matrix implies the "interior disjoint" relation.

Comment: What do you mean by interior disjoint? Do you mean "boundary intersection ok, just nothing inside"? Can you show and example?

Comment: "Interior disjoint" means that the objects are allowed to touch but not to overlap. As you said: boundary intersection ok, just nothing inside. See an example here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Interior-disjoint.svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to think about this in terms of a union of the "is disjoint" and "touches only on the borders" cases.

Those relationships are (imaginatively) known as "disjoint" and "touches".

Here is an example in SpatiaLite:

```
spatialite> SELECT ST_Touches(GeomFromText("POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))"), GeomFromText("POLYGON((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 2 1, 0 1))"));
1
spatialite> SELECT ST_Within(GeomFromText("POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))"), GeomFromText("POLYGON((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 2 1, 0 1))"));                                                                                                                                         
0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
spatialite> SELECT ST_Disjoint(GeomFromText("POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))"), GeomFromText("POLYGON((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 2 1, 0 1))"));                                                                                                                                        
0
```

In JTS, one way would be to call [relate](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/operation/relate/RelateOp.html) to get the [IntersectionMatrix](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/IntersectionMatrix.html), then check for [isDisjoint](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/IntersectionMatrix.html#isDisjoint%28%29) || [isTouches](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/IntersectionMatrix.html#isTouches%28int,%20int%29)

There might be a slightly more efficient way by defining your own IntersectionMatrix check based on encoding into the DE-9IM format, but I find that to be the geo equivalent to regular expressions:

> Given a problem you think "*I know, I'll use DE-9IM for this*". Now you
>   have two problems.

Comment: What about the following DE-9IM pattern: "F********" will this work?

Comment: Difficult to say - I'm not that smart. It might work for some cases, and not others (especially for degenerate polygons, like a single point, or a closed line). So you need to test/debug/test. And then debug months later when you find a problem. Or use the functions someone else debugged. I'd do the latter - calculating the matrix is the expensive part. so the benefit will be small if unnoticeable.